# Filtering data with the FilterPredicate with another function

Tags: typescript, filter, datatable, angular5, datasource

I've been tasked to improve on a Filter function within a web platform. Several components inherit from a parent component "Root-table" and these components display tables with a variety of information.

The root table has a filter function with data tables, replacing dataSource.filterPredicate with their own custom filter. Some of the child components overwrite the parent component when necessary, and they want me to remove the need to overwrite.

Essentially, some of the components have clickable buttons to apply other filter terms, besides a search box. When they overwrite the parent filter function, they are actually running the code over again with a single line added at the bottom to filter the results against these button filters.

Unfortunately, they did not plan ahead with this design and 1) Not all objects have a filter and 2) Each object that does have a filter uses a different name for which piece of data it is based on. (Booking.status as 1 example, Vehicle.type as another)

Here comes my problem. They are seemingly adamant about not having child functions overwriting a parent with pretty much the exact same code bar 1 line. (About 15 lines total).

The first ideas I had were, passing a function into filter that is optional and given by children when necessary, to run that one line. Alternatively, having a parent function that is always called but does nothing, only overwritten by children that need it.

Neither of these are possible because the filterPredicate is in a scope of it's own, and I can't access other functions from filter, nor can I alter the parameters that MUST fit the base filter (Such being data: T, filter: string).

They've now given the suggestion to have a function that returns the filter function, with extra functionality added in there, though this ONLY runs once.

I'm new to Typescript, and have no idea what else I can do. Besides suggesting they leave it as is with some minor dupe code, or restructuring their objects to better fit this design (Both of which have been rejected), do I have any other options?